# How to change subscription status from down to replicating

Tags: postgresql, pglogical

I am trying to replicate postgresql database from provider node to subscriber node.
I have followed tutorial from **http://bonesmoses.org/2016/10/14/pg-phriday-perfectly-logical/** and created provider node and added a table to replication set and similarly created subscriber to subscribe to this table and subscription is working fine for this.
I added few more tables after that which are part of different database but on same postgres instance and have added these tables to new replication set but for this set replication is not working  and subscriber is coming as down for this set.
How can I make this subscription as replicating for the replication sets I have added later.

Below are the commands I have run on **provider** node:

Step 1 : Ran the pg_dump file to import the DDL commands

```
psql -U postgres -d databasename1 < exportDDL.pgsql
```

Step 2: Created the provider node

```
SELECT pglogical.create_node(
node_name := 'db_provider',
dsn := 'host=docker-container-ip port=5432 dbname=databasename1'
```

);

Step 3: Created replication state

```
SELECT pglogical.create_replication_set(
set_name := 'qrtz',
replicate_insert := TRUE, replicate_update := TRUE,
replicate_delete := TRUE, replicate_truncate := TRUE);
```

Step 4: Added three tables to this set

```
SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(
set_name := 'qrtz', relation := ‘qrtz_logs', 
synchronize_data := TRUE);

SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(
set_name := 'qrtz', relation := ‘qrtz_errors', 
synchronize_data := TRUE);

SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(
set_name := 'qrtz', relation := ‘qrtz_calendars', 
synchronize_data := TRUE);
```

**Subscriber node:**

Step 1:  Ran DDL commands using pg_dump file

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres < exportDDL.pgsql
```

Step 2: Created subscriber node

```
SELECT pglogical.create_node(
node_name := 'db_subscriber',
dsn := 'host=docker-container-ip port=5432 dbname=postgres');
```

Step 3: Created subscription

```
SELECT pglogical.create_subscription(subscription_name := 'qrtz_data’,  
replication_sets := array['qrtz'],
 provider_dsn := 'host=provider-docker-container-ip port=5432 
 dbname=databasename1');
```

Step 4: checked status by using

```
Select * from pglogical.show_subscription_status
```

It showed status as **down** for subscription qrtz_data

Comment: `ALTER SUBSCRIPTION name ENABLE` of course does not help?.. you have to give technical details

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have edited the post with technical details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Down means the subscription did not succeed: there is usually some problem. Check Postgres logs for the errors. Once you resolve the errors, re-create the subscription by dropping and creating it again. Check the status. If down again, check error log again. Keep iterating until the status is `initializing` and then `replicating`.

Comment: Hi, could u give some hint on where the log is located? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Postgres error log. If you're running it yourself, it should be in `/var/log/postgresql/main-14-postgresql.log` (14 is the Postgres version, it'll vary with what you have installed).

Comment: spelling - you mean postgresql-14-main.log.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing subscription and recreating it again but status started with `initialising` but became `down` again.

### Root cause

It is a very weird state and not sure how to overcome it and understand the root cause but I've managed to resolve this with following steps.

For us, reason was shutting down source and target databases and that was somehow resulting into this out of sync status.

Note : If your subscription status is `replicating` and source/target are out of sync then run the command mentioned in #additional note only and no need to apply resolution.

### Resolution

If your subscription status is `down`

- Drop pglogical extension
- Create pglogical configuration for your publisher and subscriber databases again.

### Additional Note

Last step will put subscription back in `replicating` state fine for new entries but lag might still be there.

So to ensure both the source and target tables are in sync, run this below command

```
SELECT pglogical.alter_subscription_resynchronize_table('${SUBSCRIPTION_NAME}', '${SCHEMA_NAME}.${TABLE_NAME}');
```

In a matter of few minutes both the tables have data in sync.